# Common practice in Common Lisp to pass options to a library at load/compile time

Tags: common-lisp

## Background

I'm writing a Common Lisp library containing a reader macro.
Now it concerns me that my reader macro may overwrite existing one which has the same dispatching macro character. To avoid this conflict, I want to provide some way for users to control whether my reader macro should be defined or not from outside of the library.

The special variable `*features*` seems to serve this purpose, evaluating

```
(push :some-suppression-flag *features*)
```

before loading the library and

```
#-some-suppression-flag (set-dispatch-macro-character ...)
```

in the library.

I know [Named Readtables](https://github.com/melisgl/named-readtables) can solve the "global readtable problem", but I don't want to use it to make my library have few dependencies.

## Question

Is the above way using `*features*` a good manner to pass some options to a library at load/compile time?
Or are there common practice to do so?

Comment: I'd have a function to install the reader macros to a given readtable. See for example FSet or SERIES.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The libraries seem to contain many useful techniques to create Common Lisp libraries. I'll check them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just provide a function which the user can call:

```
(defun enable-foo-syntax (&optional (enabled-p t))
  ...)

(enable-foo-syntax t)    ; on
(enable-foo-syntax nil)  ; off
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's simple and sufficient!
Actually, I want to define my reader macro by default (without calling any functions), so I'm going to employ a strategy to store the existing one internally and restore it when a user calls a function to deactivate my reader macro. (The function must be called immediately after loading the library.) If someone knows better ways, please leave comments.